# Edit Path Programmatically

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to edit a path programmatically?

I'm trying to create a userControl which acts as a horizontal meter whose width is dynamic.  I have created a path in the xaml and planned on having an int property which controls the width of the meter dynamically.  It has rounded edges so I had planned to edit the x coordinates on the right end of the meter to shrink the meter but keep the same rounded corners.  I see the Data property on the path but don't understand how I can edit it.

Is there a better approach, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're setting Path.Data directly, you won't be able to edit it in code behind. If you want to be able to do that, you should use `PathGeometry` instead. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> As you can see from the preceding
>   examples, the two mini-languages are
>   very similar. It's always possible to
>   use a PathGeometry in any situation
>   where you could use a StreamGeometry;
>   so which one should you use? Use a
>   StreamGeometry when you don't need to
>   modify the path after creating it; use
>   a PathGeometry if you do need to
>   modify the path.

The following two Path's are equivalent, the later one can be modified in code behind

```
<!-- Path 1: Using StreamGeometry -->
<Path x:Name="MyPath"
      Stroke="Black"
      StrokeThickness="10"
      Margin="20"
      Data="M 10,10 L 100,10 L 100,200 L 10,200 Z"/>
<!-- Path 2: Using PathGeometry-->
<Path x:Name="MyPath2"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="10"
    Margin="20">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigure x:Name="figure1" StartPoint="10, 10" IsClosed="True">
                    <LineSegment x:Name="line1" Point="100, 10"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="line2" Point="100, 200"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="line3" Point="10, 200"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

To modify MyPath2 in code behind, you can access the `PathFigure` and `LineSegment`s either by Name

```
private void MovePathHorizontally()
{
    figure1.StartPoint = new Point(figure1.StartPoint.X + 10, figure1.StartPoint.Y);
    line1.Point = new Point(line1.Point.X + 10, line1.Point.Y);
    line2.Point = new Point(line2.Point.X + 10, line2.Point.Y);
    line3.Point = new Point(line3.Point.X + 10, line3.Point.Y);
}
```

or like this

```
private void MovePathHorizontally()
{
    PathGeometry pathGeometry = MyPath2.Data as PathGeometry;
    PathFigureCollection pathFigures = pathGeometry.Figures;
    foreach (PathFigure pathFigure in pathFigures)
    {
        pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(pathFigure.StartPoint.X + 10, pathFigure.StartPoint.Y);

        PathSegmentCollection pathSegments = pathFigure.Segments;
        foreach (PathSegment pathSegment in pathSegments)
        {
            if (pathSegment is LineSegment)
            {
                LineSegment lineSegment = pathSegment as LineSegment;
                lineSegment.Point = new Point(lineSegment.Point.X + 10, lineSegment.Point.Y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```